# How to make case insensitive in Map

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I have two objects 'Job Document History' and 'Job Position Transactional'. JPT is the master and JDH is child. In JDh i have field version. It should be unique for each relationship with JPT. I wrote trigger on JDH and trying to validate the duplicate values. Here the problem is Map is Case Sensitive. I want But i am

> getting NullPointerException

when i am trying to enter opposite letters(like if 'A' already there but i given 'a').

Below is the my code:

```
trigger DuplicateVersion on Job_Document_History__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String, Job_Document_History__c> versionMap = new Map<String, Job_Document_History__c>();
    Set<string> jobPositionTran = new Set<string>();

    for (Job_Document_History__c jobDocHis : System.Trigger.new) {

        if ((jobDocHis.Version__c != null) && (System.Trigger.isInsert || (jobDocHis.Version__c != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(jobDocHis.Id).Version__c))) 

        {
            jobPositionTran.add(jobDocHis.Job_Position_Transactional__c);
            if (versionMap.containsKey(jobDocHis.Version__c)) {
                jobDocHis.Version__c.addError('Another new document history has the same version Name.');
            } else {
                versionMap.put(jobDocHis.Version__c.toUpperCase(), jobDocHis);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Job_Document_History__c jobDocHis : [SELECT Version__c FROM Job_Document_History__c WHERE Job_Position_Transactional__c IN :jobPositionTran and Version__c IN :versionMap.KeySet()]) {
        Job_Document_History__c newjobDocHis = versionMap.get(jobDocHis.Version__c.toUpperCase());
        newjobDocHis.Version__c.addError('This version is already exists.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Basic idea would be add to map string in lower case and check that as well. F.e. `versionMap.containsKey(jobDocHis.Version__c.toLowerCase()))` or `versionMap.put(jobDocHis.Version__c.toLowerCase(), jobDocHis);`

Comment: Hi Kurunve, I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve -- make map case insensitive?. And what kind of exception appears?

Comment: Why don't you just make the field unique case-insensitive instead of reinventing the wheel in apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [toUpperCase()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_toUpperCase) and covert the key to all in upper case.

```
versionMap.put(jobDocHis.Version__c.toUpperCase(), jobDocHis);
```

Comment: i tried this also but still it showing the error message. Error message is "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger HR_DuplicateVersion caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: HR_DuplicateVersion: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.HR_DuplicateVersion: line 26, column 1". Line no 26 is "newjobDocHis.Version__c.addError('This version is already exists.');".

Comment: @VijayKumar versionMap.get(jobDocHis.Version__c); -> you need to use here a versionMap.get(jobDocHis.Version__c.toUpperCase());.

Comment: @VijayKumar - that error means the key already exists thus your code is working as you expected. You asked for it to be case insensitive.

Comment: @Eric That error means that newjobDocHis is null

Comment: @kurunve - Yup. I read it wrong - need coffee......

Comment: I got the result as expected . Added .toUpperCase() in put() and get() methods. Updated latest code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to bypass the difference between 'A' and 'a' ,try to use containsIgnoreCase('string') method of String.By using this u can make the map key unique in ur case.